# Select top-most folder in a hierarchy by given criteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I'm using MySQL (5.7.20) to store a folder hierarchy. Each folder is stored together with all direct and indirect parents including the distance. As an example, the following folders

```
A
+- B
   + C
   + D
```

would be stored like this:

```
parent | child | dist
-------+-------+-----
A      | A     | 0
A      | B     | 1
A      | C     | 2
A      | D     | 2
B      | B     | 0
B      | C     | 1
B      | D     | 1
C      | C     | 0
D      | D     | 0
```

Additionally, there is another table that links a folder to one or many users, like this:

```
child | user
------+-----
A     | U1
B     | U1
C     | U2
D     | U2
```

What I'm now trying to achieve is to query this hierarchy by user in a way that *only* the highest matches in the hierarchy are returned.

So as in the example above, if I query for folders of user `U1`, I only want `A` as a result, because the second match `B` is a child of `A`. On the other hand, if I query for folders of user `U2`, the result should be `C, D` as both folders are on the same hierarchy level.

The closest query I could imagine was `SELECT child, dist AS d FROM folders JOIN users ON folders.child = users.child GROUP BY folders.parent HAVING d = min(d);` but unfortunately it is not giving the right results, as for example a query for user `U1` would still give folders `A,B` as a result.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: What if A had another child (E), related to U2? Would asking for U1 return C, D and E?

Comment: Exactly, this should result in `C,D,E` for user `U2` as none of the folders would be parent (or child) of another one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this. All the results from `users` table except those that have a parent in users:

```
SELECT u.user, u.child
FROM users AS u 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM users AS u2
             JOIN folder AS f 
             ON f.parent = u2.child
        WHERE f.child = u.child
          AND f.dist > 0         -- this could be: AND f.parent <> f.child
          AND u2.user = u.user
      ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well! The only problem left is that I also need other columns from the `folders` table as well. But I guess I could just join the result with the folders table again.

Comment: What other columns are there in folders?

Comment: The `parent` column for example should be part of the result

Comment: So, for the U2 case (with C,D,E output), what would the parents be? All parents of C,D and E?

Comment: like `[(C,B), (D,B), (E, A)]`, the first value being the folder/child and the second value the parent

Comment: So the immediate parent you mean. Because the question uses "parent" and means ancestor.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, the immediate parent

Comment: Yes, you can use LEFT JOIN for that `LEFT JOIN folders f ON f.child = u.child AND f.dist = 1`. You'll get `(C,B), (D,B), (E, A)` for U2 and `(A, null)` for U1.